# How to use inline svg in React without colliding id's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

Is it possible to use inline *SVG* that is stored in a separate .svg file in React? Classes inside *SVG* should not be modified and any id's should be changed so that no id collisions occur.

I tried to use *svgr* library with the following webpack configuration of the *svgr* library:

```
  const { relative } = require('path');
  const context = __dirname;

  ...

  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ({resource}) => ({
      loader: '@svgr/webpack',
      options: {
        svgoConfig: {
          plugins: [
            { prefixIds: {
                prefixIds: true,
                prefixClassNames: false,
            }},
            { cleanupIDs: {
                prefix: {
                  toString() {
                    return `_${hash(relative(context, resource))}_`;
                  }
                },
                minify: true
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }),
  },

  ...
```

Example React code:

```
import Icon from 'icon.svg'

export default () => <div>
    <Icon />
    <Icon />
</div>
```

Example icon.svg content:

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100"
>
  <path
    fill="green"
    class="test_class"
    id="test_id"
    d="M 0 0 C 0 50, 40 20, 100 100 V 0 Z"
  />
</svg>
```

Unfortunetally the *svgr* by default has no concept of "multiple instances of the same *SVG*"

Above webpack configuration allows to import the same *SVG* from multiple files and id's inside rendered *svg* are different each time, because path is different, so appended hash is different too.

The problem is that it doesn't work with many instances of the same component (`Icon`) and will result in several dom nodes with the same id. The transformed version of "test_id" will be repeated two times in the example above.

I tried to use *svg-react-loader* library, but it can modify only top-level svg node.

EDIT: i need intact classes, because they are used to access some parts of svg from CSS, for example:
CSS code:

```
.imported_svg .test_class {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Inline SVG works best with simple icons that uses `fill="currentColor"` and doesn't have id's for complex gradients or masks.

Comment: In your example SVG, the `class` and `id` are useless, so I'd say to just get rid of them.

Comment: @EmileBergeron So more complex SVG should be coded manually (not imported from .svg file)?

Comment: Either manually or as `<img>` tags source.

Comment: Manually styling a generated SVG sounds wrong, I'd put a class on the SVG itself outside of the SVG file (a `className` when rendering it in React) and use that to identify the right SVG.

Comment: @EmileBergeron you mean that kind of svg should be generated by React the same way as normal html elements?

Comment: If you're messing with it manually, yes, it could be defined completely in a React component.

Comment: @EmileBergeron What about gradient and masks?